# Using a dictionary to filter out required tweets

Tags: r, dictionary, filter, tweets

I'm trying to filter out tweets but stuck. I want to have a dictionary containing all the english words plus the words I add and by using this I want to filter out my tweets. As I have a dataframe containing tweets and the text column is:

```
        text
1 |  @a_siab @sardarbabak999 @BushraGohar @jafarshahmp @Palwasha_Abbas @Khadimhussain4 @Khushal_Khattak @SPOX_ANP @mjdawar @AsgharAchakzaii @AmirHaiderKH @MianIftikharHus @khaistak50 @SangeenKhan 
2 |  @KPKUpdates @ImranKhanPTI @jhagra @Shah_FarmanPTI @AsadQaiserPTI @MushtaqGhaniPTI @PervezKhattakCM @ziataj @AtifKhanpti It's much better than anp and mma time
3 |  Easy load was started by PTI and not ANP #KaptaanFailedInKP
4 |  @Palwasha_Abbas @Gulalai_Ismail This was much needed and people are happy with using it which avoided traffic issues. Your only issue is PTI buried ANP easyload shops forever now it’s obvious you will cry
5 |  @x_anp <U+304A><U+3081><U+3067><U+3068><U+3046>!!
6 |  Tourism &amp; Poor Condition of Swat Roads, Part-2 #Swat #Tourism #Kpk #CareTakerPM #NasarullMuik #MaryamNawaz #PMLN #PTI #ImranKhan #Newsonepk #ANP #Nadia @nadia_a_mirza #Pakistan 
7 |  @Palwasha_Abbas Kuch samjhayein in ko... Articles likhnay say character thek nhe hotay... ANP is history. @BushraGohar
8 |  <U+062F> <U+06A9><U+0644><U+064A> <U+0631><U+0648><U+063A> <U+062A><U+0631><U+06CC><U+0646><U+0647> <U+0686><U+0627><U+067E><U+06D0><U+0631><U+0647> <U+062F><U+064A> <U+0627><U+0648> <U+062E><U+0627><U+0646><U+062F><U+064A> <U+067E><U+0633><U+06D0> <U+06CC><U+0648> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0646><U+06CC> <U+0648><U+0631><U+062A><U+0647> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062E><U+0628><U+0631><U+06D0> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+064A> @AbdullahMalikJ @a_baittani @SherazMmd @MianIftikharHus @anp_mohmand @MisbahUtmani @takkar1234 @anp_mohmand
9 |  <U+0648> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0646><U+06CC> <U+0648><U+0631><U+062A><U+0647> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062E><U+0628><U+0631><U+06D0> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+064A> @AbdullahMalikJ @a_baittani @SherazMmd @MianIftikharHus @anp_mohmand @MisbahUtmani @takkar1234 @anp_mohmand @AmirHaiderKH @MianIftikharHus @khaistak50 @SangeenKhan ANP is history
10 |  @MianIftikharHus Pti ki govt bilkul bhi ideal nhi ti magar mazrat k sath anp or mma ki pechli govt se pti ki govt kafi behtr ti .hospitals or schools me tabdeeli ayi hy koi mane ya na mane.
11 |  <U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062E><U+0628><U+0631><U+06D0> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+064A> @AbdullahMalikJ @a_baittani @SherazMmd @MianIftikharHus @anp_mohmand @MisbahUtmani @takkar1234 @anp_mohmand @AmirHaiderKH @MianIftikharHus @khaistak50 @SangeenKhan ANP ki koi history nahi hai
```

The required dataframe should be like:

```
        text
1 |  @a_siab @sardarbabak999 @BushraGohar @jafarshahmp @Palwasha_Abbas @Khadimhussain4 @Khushal_Khattak @SPOX_ANP @mjdawar @AsgharAchakzaii @AmirHaiderKH @MianIftikharHus @khaistak50 @SangeenKhan 
2 |  @KPKUpdates @ImranKhanPTI @jhagra @Shah_FarmanPTI @AsadQaiserPTI @MushtaqGhaniPTI @PervezKhattakCM @ziataj @AtifKhanpti It's much better than anp and mma time
3 |  Easy load was started by PTI and not ANP #KaptaanFailedInKP
4 |  @Palwasha_Abbas @Gulalai_Ismail This was much needed and people are happy with using it which avoided traffic issues. Your only issue is PTI buried ANP easyload shops forever now it’s obvious you will cry
5 |  NA
6 |  Tourism &amp; Poor Condition of Swat Roads, Part-2 #Swat #Tourism #Kpk #CareTakerPM #NasarullMuik #MaryamNawaz #PMLN #PTI #ImranKhan #Newsonepk #ANP #Nadia @nadia_a_mirza #Pakistan 
7 |  NA
8 |  <U+062F> <U+06A9><U+0644><U+064A> <U+0631><U+0648><U+063A> <U+062A><U+0631><U+06CC><U+0646><U+0647> <U+0686><U+0627><U+067E><U+06D0><U+0631><U+0647> <U+062F><U+064A> <U+0627><U+0648> <U+062E><U+0627><U+0646><U+062F><U+064A> <U+067E><U+0633><U+06D0> <U+06CC><U+0648> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0646><U+06CC> <U+0648><U+0631><U+062A><U+0647> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062E><U+0628><U+0631><U+06D0> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+064A> @AbdullahMalikJ @a_baittani @SherazMmd @MianIftikharHus @anp_mohmand @MisbahUtmani @takkar1234 @anp_mohmand
9 |  <U+0648> <U+0644><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0646><U+06CC> <U+0648><U+0631><U+062A><U+0647> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+0631><U+069A><U+062A><U+06CC><U+0627> <U+062E><U+0628><U+0631><U+06D0> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+064A> @AbdullahMalikJ @a_baittani @SherazMmd @MianIftikharHus @anp_mohmand @MisbahUtmani @takkar1234 @anp_mohmand @AmirHaiderKH @MianIftikharHus @khaistak50 @SangeenKhan ANP is history
10 |  NA
11 |  NA
```

Then, I can easily remove the  by converting dataframe to corpus.
I just want this. How to obtain such dictionary? Would it be possible by using a dictionary? Or Should I use classifier or something else. Please, explain your answer what should I do?. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem you are trying to solve? How should the tweets be filtered? Are you trying to remove all non-English tweets?

Comment: Yes but there is roman english as well like in 10 and 11. In Pakistan people use message typing to write anything like if it is in English "ANP is the history" but in roman/message typing it is "ANP ek history h". I want to remove these and just have related political tweets.